# Mixing & Calling .Net 4.5 from .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have an application the is written and targeting .NET Framework 4.0. 
In one of the Base Project I have to add a reference that is done in .NET 4.5. So, in order to build this project I had to switch it is target framework to 4.5.

Now, the problem that VS is complaining about each project in the application that is referencing this base project.

1. Is there a way I can make this base project target framework 4.5 without having to changing all the project's that is referencing it.
2. Can I mix both frameworks and call from a .NET 4 project to a .NET 4.5 project.
3. The best solution would be if I can use the new external reference built in .NET 4.5 (that cause all this trouble) from within the base project without having to change the base project Target to .NET 4.5. Is that possible?

Basically I would like to use this reference built for 4.5 without having to change the whole application target framework.

Comment: Why not change them all? .NET 4.5 is a binary replacement of 4.0. That means that simply installing the runtime replaces the 4.0 binaries with 4.5. There is no reason to mix versions when you will end up running on 4.5 anyway. You can use a tool like the [Target Framework Migrator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13) to upgrade all projects at once

Comment: Another option is to remain at 4.0 and use compatiblity packages like Bcl.Async, Bcl.HttpClient etc. This won't give you any of the runtime advantages like background garbage collection

Comment: This will cause more problems than having to deal with upgrade issues. I'm  taking the upgrade path for now. I was just hoping there might be a simple out of the gate way to do it. Thank you again for all your valuable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the build warnings do a good job of describing what will happen.

I create a solution with two projects:

- ProjectA (Framework version 4.0)
- ProjectB (Framework version 4.5)

ProjectA references ProjectB.

Warnings:

```
The referenced project 'ProjectB' is targeting a higher framework version (4.5) than this project’s current target framework version (4.0). This may lead to build failures if types from assemblies outside this project’s target framework are used by any project in the dependency chain.   


The primary reference "c:\Scratch\ProjectA\ProjectB\bin\Debug\ProjectB.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". ProjectA    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1819
```

Your best bet is to update all of the projects involved.

Comment: I know the VS warning and errors.
I guess I'll have to upgrade after all.

Comment: This stuff about upgrading is obvious. What actually is meant is that upgrading is not an option because there is some reason for not doing that, like running an application on Windows XP.